# Equivalence Relations Analysis

Tags: equivalence-relations

A relation R is defined on a set $ A:(a, b, c) as R: ((a, c), (b, b))$   then the relation R is ?

A) transitive and antisymmetric
B)transitive and symmetric
C)symmetric and antisymmetric
D)reflexive and transitive

I couldn't relate this question with any choices.
To me it is not symmetric because does not include (c,a) and not transitive because of (a,c) does not included in R as (c,?).

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's not symmetric.

But it *IS* transitive. Because there is no pair of the form $(c,?)$, there is nothing to check for transitivity.

So what you've said rules out choices B and C. But now you just have to decide if it's reflexive or antisymmetric to decide if it's A or D.

Comment: I said A and accordint to the answers it seems wrong. Then I will go with D. Thanks for checking.

Comment: It cannot be D. It is not reflexive since there is no (a,a). I think A is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I will discuss with the instructor too.

Answer (score 0):

To be transitive then, because of the $(a,c)$ for every $(c,?)$ it must include $(a,?)$.  But there is no need for there to be any $(c,?)$ in the first place.  If there is no $(c,?)$ there's nothing to check.

It is transitive.  For  $(a,c)$ there aren't any $(c,?)$ so there aren't any thing to check.  For $(b,b)$ then only $(b,?)$ there is is $(b,b)$ and we have $(b,b)$ so it passes.

Its not symmetric as There is an $(a,c)$ so to be symmetric there would need to be an $(c,a)$ and there isn't.

To be antisymmetric for every $(x,y); x\ne y$ we can not have $(y,x)$.  The only $(x,y); x\ne y$ we have is $(a,c)$ and we don't have $(c,a)$.  So it is antisymmetric.

To be reflexive we need $(a,a), (b,b)$ and $(c,c)$ and we don't have those all so it's not reflexive